# Merge previous item with next item if previuos item endswith \\

Tags: python

I need help with merging previous and next item in a list while previous item endswith '\'. Example:

```
my_list = ['zero_item','first\\','second\\','third\\', 'fourth', 'another_item', 'next_item', 'last_item']
```

Expected result:

```
merged_items_list = ['zero_item','first\\second\\third\\fourth', 'another_item', 'next_item', 'last_item']
```

Comment: duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70816383/concatenate-items-in-a-python-list-if-is-at-the-end-of-item/70816712#70816712

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if list is not so big we can get result with join, replace, split.

```
SPACER = ' ' # select spacer not in list.
print(SPACER.join(my_list).replace(f'\\{SPACER}', '\\').split(SPACER))
```