# Concatenate items in a python list if '\\' is at the end of item

Tags: python, list, merge, concatenation

I need to merge with next item in a list if previous item has '\' at the end. Example:

```
original_list = ['first.key=First value', 'second.key=Second value, first line\\', 
'Second value, second line\\', 'Second value, third line\\', 'Second value, fourth 
line', 'third.key=Third value']
```

Expected result is:

```
desired_list = ['first.key=First value', 'second.key=Second value,first line\\ Second 
value, second line\\ Second value, third line\\ Second value, fourth line', 
'third.key=Third value']
```

Do not assume that the first item ending with '\' is the second item in the list. I dont know which will it be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a crude solution, but should be working:

```
desired_list = original_list[:1]
for x in original_list[1:]:
    if desired_list[-1].endswith('\\'):
        desired_list[-1] += x
    else:
        desired_list.append(x)
print(desired_list)
```

If you work with huge lists, it may be worth to think of some optimization.

Comment: Thank you. This is working for the example list above. But if we do not assume that the first item ending with '\\' is the second item in the list and we actually dont know which will it be, how would this look like?
I will include this condition to avoid misleading anyone else.

Comment: It should work anyway - it just checks lastly updated element of desired_list, iteratively going through all elements in original list.

Comment: I like the way you initialize with `desired_list = original_list[:1]` instead of `original_list[0]`, it means it will work even with empty input.

Comment: @Maciej Wrobel, Thank you! Really. It does work. Have a nice evening.